# Indexing values using a for loop and numpy for Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm looking to transition from Matlab to Python with numpy. I am having some difficulties understanding array indexing using numpy.

As an example, I'm looking to use a 'for' loop to assign the inner elements of a row vector to be a specific value. Indexing in numpy seems to be unique to when it comes to indexing rank 1 column arrays versus row arrays.

```py
# Python:
import nump as np
from numpy import*
import scipy.linalg

N = 5
L = 1.0
dx = L / N
S = 10.0 ** -2.0
k = 500.0

aW = zeros((1, N))

for i in range(1, (N-1)):
    aE[0, i] = k * S / dx
```

```matlab
% Matlab:
N=5;
L=1.0;
dx=L/N;
S=10^(-2.0);
k=500.0;

aW=zeros(1,N);

for i = 2:N-1
    aE(i)=k*S/dx;
end
```

Is it necessary for me to specify the row index of 0, instead of just stating:

'aE[i] = k * S / dx'

Matlab doesn't seem to care about the dimensions of the matrix when assigning elements based on an single input for the index.

I don't have an issue with stating the row index. It makes me more conscious of my variable dimensions. I just want verification that it's necessary. Perhaps I'm setting up the vector incorrectly. I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: In `numpy` `aE[0]` is really `aE[0, :]`.  It indexes the first dimension of the array.  You could have defined the array as `aE = np.zeros((N,)`, in which case it would be 1d.  A key difference is that in MATLAB everything is 2d (or larger).

Comment: Why are you setting all the values of the array iteratively (with the same scalar value)?   In my old MATLAB days that would have been inefficient.

Comment: In `numpy` the leading dimensions are the outer ones; in MATLAB it's the trailing ones.  So you could also have defined  `aE=np.zeros((N,1))` to make a 'column vector', and iterated with `aE[i]`.  Sometimes that's necessary, but usually 1d arrays are just fine.

Comment: The code is from an undergrad assignment. Perhaps including it in my question was a poor example considering you could just assign elements 2:N-1 as the constant scalar value. That being said, my concern is more in regards to the manner of the indexing. From what I can garner, it appears as though iterating over a row vector would require a declaration of the row (ie. 0 in this scenario). Which is fine, just a nuance I'll have to consider. I may just stick to column vectors as you mentioned. I'm not sure how often this may arise in my code. In my case, it may depend on the data I import.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid iterating using for loops, instead try to solve the problem using broadcasting.

Read about numpy broadcasting

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

You can do this for example.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.full((2,3), 10)
array([[10, 10, 10],
       [10, 10, 10]])
```

or

```
>>> a = np.ones((2,3))
>>> a
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
>>> a * 10
array([[10., 10., 10.],
       [10., 10., 10.]])
```

or

```
>>> b = np.zeros((2,3))
>>> b
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
>>> b+10
array([[10., 10., 10.],
       [10., 10., 10.]])
```